# Web api 2 - Register, redirect and handling errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I just started my journey with WebApi2. I have customized my apiController which registers users. Now I want to handle it on my page. 
I created a controller and made a view for it. 
Registration of users works correct. I wondering, how can I handle any registration errors (like invalid model, where error fields will be marked red and error message will be displayed next to it) and eventually, automatically redirect user to a secret page when registration was successful. 
I have the following code so far:

```
var register = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Account/Register",
            type: "POST",
            data:  $("#registrationForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                //how to redirect to secret page
            },
            error: function (message) {
                //how to handle error messages with dataannotations
            }
        });
        return false;
    };

    $("#register").click(register);
```

I suppose I should just parse some JSON but I am asking about best practices how to do it.

Comment: The `error` function of jQuery's AJAX method is for request errors, i.e. the endpoint couldn't be reached. You should do form validation prior to making this call to `/api/Account/Register`. If the client-side validation passes, but the endpoint can't validate the data for some reason, you'll have to specify that in the response, which you'll get back in `success: function(data)`.

Comment: You might not be correct since api endpoint returns IHttpActionResult

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data) {
    //here you can handle response from server. If registration fails you should return 
    //validation errors, if not you can return session_token and redirect to some other page (for example)
},
error: function (message) {
    //to handle this - you should throw httpexception in your controller method with 500 error code 
    //and with some short error description.
}


//web api exception throwing example:
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, 
"this item does not exist");
```